# jQuery:Trying to append the options to select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-chosen, jquery-append

Hi I am trying to append the options based on input to select tag. but options are not appending. I am not even getting the errors so where is the fault not able to understand.

**HTML**

```
  <div class="col-lg-5">
      <div class="input-group">
          <label>Select type of Graph</label>    
          <select data-placeholder="Select Field..." id="graph_name" style="width:300px;" name="team_name" class="chosen-select" tabindex="2">

          </select>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$('#field_name').change(function() {
  var fieldname = $('#field_name option:selected').val();
  $.post('<?php echo BASE_URL . 'php/processing/formDashboard/graph/showPossibleGraphs.php?id=' . $_GET['id']; ?>', {fieldname: fieldname}, function(data) {
    $.each(data.graphs, function(index, value) {
      $.each(value, function(index, value) {
        console.log(value.id);
        console.log(value.text);
        var option = '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.text+'</option>';
        $('#graph_name').append(option);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Here is the screenshot
[image: This is the image when i selected the option from one dropdown & the data came from script in JSON format]

This is the image when i selected the option from one dropdown & the data came from script in JSON format

[image: This is the firebug debugging screenshot that shows that data is getting appended but on click it is showing nothing]

This is the firebug debugging screenshot that shows that data is getting appended but on click it is showing nothing
My sample data is this:

```
sample data: {
  "status":"OK",
  "response":200,
  "graphs":[[
    {"id":"B","text":"Bar Chart"},
    {"id":"D","text":"Doughnut Chart"},
    {"id":"P","text":"Pie Chart"}
  ]]
}
```

Comment: where is `'#field_name'` ? have you getting data in console? `console.log(value.text);`

Comment: i have not added the field name select tag as values are coming to value.id & value.text i can see this on console the opint is it is not appending to the destination

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> EDIT Based on Chat

Since you're dynamically forming the `select`, you must trigger the chosen plugin.

```
 $('#graph_name').trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Add it after appending the options. It will work

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mohamedrias/yurhhy1m/1/)**

You're trying to append the string directly. But you must append the DOM element.

```
  var option = '<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.text+'</option>';
  $('#graph_name').append(option);
```

It must be

```
  var option = $('<option value="'+value.id+'">'+value.text+'</option>');
  $('#graph_name').append(option);
```

Even better, instead of appending to the DOM tree on every iteration. Load it an array and then set the html() in the `select`. It will improve the performance.

Comment: Actually the problem is it is appending but not showing to dropdown. Instead when i saw it in the firebug, it is showing me appended but the whole div i have seen is in disabled format. what is it i am not getting

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to look at?

Comment: i will add the screenshot here. jsfiddle will take time i have chosen plugin that i am using to modernize the dropdown

Comment: for both of them display: none property is set in css. It's very specific to chosen plugin. Please setup a jsfiddle to check.

Comment: i tried at my level you can correct it link:http://jsfiddle.net/sagar_barwade/jyn1jr05/

Comment: Great! Looking at it. Please share some sample data for `data.graphs`

Comment: what the fish......when i remove the chosen class for second dropdown then it is showing me the output in the dropdown the problem is with chosen class for second dropdown....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75570/discussion-between-mohamedrias-and-shaggie).

Answer (score 3):

Another alternative would be:

```
$.each(selectValues, function(key, value) {   
     $('#graph_name')
         .append($("<option></option>")
         .attr("value",key)
         .text(value)); 
});
```